# Do I need to reindex when I repoint SOLR to the copy of a database?

Tags: database, solr, lucene, alfresco, solrcloud

I am currently using SOLR 6 included with alfresco search services 2.0

I have an S3 database that is fully indexed, but I have now made a copy of this database. The database is a different one, however all the documents stored inside the database are identical. Would repointing the SOLR server to this new database require reindexing? Or will SOLR be able to detect the same files and not require any indexing (using the indexes already created from the original database for searching).

Additionally, if I added some more documents to the copy database after duplication, will SOLR just reindex the new documents or the whole database? I guess the answer to this depends heavily on the former question.

I would be willing to try this out, but I need to know the outcome to make a very important business decision. Hence I am not able to test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Would repointing the SOLR server to this new database require re-indexing?
   No reindexing required untill and unless you have any changes to the copied database and you want those database changes to be made available to the solr server.
2. If I added some more documents to the copy database after duplication, will SOLR just re-index the new documents or the whole database?
   If you add new document/records to the copied database then you need to have a mechanism or system which will be doing the index of newly added document/records from the copied database to solr.